# Iterate through folders in a secondary Outlook Inbox using Python

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com

My biggest issue  is  that I have several email accounts attached to my profile in Outlook. They all belong to the same domain as my main one. I'm able to send and  receive as the other accounts. However, with the below  code, I'm not able  to access the Inbox  folders of the  other accounts. Just my default  one i.e. mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6). How  can I access inboxes  of the other accounts and download the attachments as that's what I need? I tried `mapi.Folders('hhh@yyy.com').Folders('Inbox').Items` and that didn't work. Any idea of  how to work this out?

```
import win32com.client
import pendulum

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6) #Can be  replaced with Messages = mapi.Folders('xxx@yyy.com').Folders('Inbox').Items . If this  happens, then no need to define  Messages below.
Messages = Inbox.Items


received_date = pendulum.now().last(pendulum.MONDAY) #Search for emails since last Monday
received_date = received_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p') #Change  the date format
messages = Messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + received_date + "'") #Restrict the received time i.e. > than or equal to last Monday
messages = Messages.Restrict("[Subject] = 'Automatic Reports'") #Title  contains   this 

outputDir = r"C:\Users\xxx\TestEmails"
try:
    for message in list(messages):
        try:
            s = message.sender
            for attachment in message.Attachments:
                attachment.SaveASFile(os.path.join(outputDir, attachment.FileName))
                print(f"attachment {attachment.FileName} from {s} saved")
        except Exception as e:
            print("error when saving the attachment:" + str(e))
except Exception as e:
    print("error when processing emails messages:" + str(e))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `Store` class instead. For example:

```
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)
```

Here the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `Namespace` class is used. But what you really need is to iterate over all stores and use the [Store.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method:

```
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
for store in mapi.Stores: 
  Inbox = store.GetDefaultFolder(6)
```

Comment: Thank you @Eugene.  Not  sure  how  to access a certain inbox in the list of  inboxes. What about  accessing  a sub folder  inside an Inbox  that is not the default  one for my email?

Comment: You can use the [Store.GetRootFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getrootfolder) to get the root folder and then iterate over all subfolders recursively or just get a particular folder.