# Filtering and saving outlook email based on a specific subject using python

Tags: python, outlook

I want to filter out emails on outlook based on a subject line that start with/ end with/ contain specific words/characters. Then I want to save those emails in a folder.

To begin with, I tried to follow the code for filtering out emails based on senders. But I am stuck:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.Folders("abc@xyz.com").Folders("Sent Items")

Filter = "[Subject] = 'Unaff'"

items = inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)
```

Comment: Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried somwthing like this?

Add this line to your code

```
    messages = Messages.Restrict("[Subject] = 'Automatic Reports'") #Title  contains  this
```

you can use the information given in this post too [Iterate through folders in a secondary Outlook Inbox using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67481097/iterate-through-folders-in-a-secondary-outlook-inbox-using-python)